Cannot connect to the Docker daemon but hello world from docker works
I've stucked on this for days, I've checked the docker is running by docker run hello-world.
But why still see the error?


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  The entirety of your question seems to be a PNG file.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the image with a [mcve], including the source code you've written, the commands you're running, and the error output you're getting, all in plain text?

docker : Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
above error messages is related to docker service. Service might be not running.
check first systemctl status docker. if status is stop, please run following commands.
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
And then, please check again .

Have you enabled docker service on your host machine? Looks like your local has enabled service but your job receiving runner has not.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
